# How to tell Laravel Eloquent about more than one one-to-many in the same Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table for spam reports on my site, and a user can appear in two different columns: as the user who made the spam report, or as the user who was reported.

```
User
- id

Spam
- reporter_user_id
- spammer_user_id
```

How can tell Eloquent that there is a one-to-many relationship between both `user` and `Spam->report_user_id`, AND `user` and `Spam->spammer_user_id`?

(And yeah, I know this is a shitty way to set up this table... it's an existing data structure that I can't change, so this is what I have to work with.)

Comment: You're following the wrong DB structure. you should have spam table as `id, user_id, type`. type should be `reporter,spammer`

Comment: Yes, but I'm working with an existing database structure. Edited my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Spam model:

```php
public function reporter() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reporter_user_id');
}

public function spammer() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'spammer_user_id');
}
```

Now, if you have a `$spam` object you can access them using:

```php
$spam->spammer; 

$spam->reporter;
```

In your user Model:

```php
public function reportedSpams() {
  return $this->hasMany(Spam::class, 'reporter_user_id');
}

public function spammed() {
  return $this->hasMany(Spam::class, 'spammer_user_id');
}
```

And now you can access all the spam reported or spammed by a given user:

```php
$user->reportedSpams;
$user->spammed;
```

Comment: In the Spam model (the top of your answer), the 2nd argument for `belongsTo()` should both be ID, and then the 3rd argument would be either `reporter_user_id` or `spammer_user_id`, right?

Comment: No, in the `belongsTo` method the second argument is the name of the foreign key in the model itself (in your case, in the Spam model). The second argument should  be `reporter_user_id` or `spammer_user_id`. The third argument is the primary key on the target table. In your case the primary key in the users table is `id`, which is also the default so you can avoid writing it

Comment: Thanks very much!